# why can't I init mutable type with null?

Tags: f#

I'm trying:

```
let mutable ncon : NCon = null
```

and getting:

```
Error   1   The type 'NCon' does not have 'null' as a proper value
```

where type is declard in this way

```
type NCon(settings : ISettings) = ...
```

I'm planning to use it as static property and init it later when user will finish the settings so what am I doing wrong? why can't I init mutable type with null?

must I use option? so to make it to be None or Some instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to supply a [AllowNullLiteral](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353608.aspx) to your NCon-Type like this:

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type NCon(settings : ISettings) = ...
```

This is because F# prevents you from using Null ... not a bad idea IMHO

To your other questions:
Yes I would rather use an option - and I would consider using a ref-cell too - but this depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Another option is `Operators.Unchecked.Defaultof<_>` which gives the best allowable approxiamation to null for a given type

Comment: true - but the clean solution would still be using an option or even a lazy value

Comment: How is `Unchecked.defaultof` different from null? (for types that default to null)

Comment: @GregRos It is not - but for example `Unchecked.defaultof<int>=0`.  The only difference is for non-nullable types (structs etc) you get a `0` value

Comment: Oh by the way. In order to compare a type without the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute to null (e.g. if you received the value from the `defaultof` operator), you will have to invoke `obj.ReferenceEquals(x, null)`. F# doesn't allow `null` comparisons for types without the attribute. You will also run into a few more problems.